# Constructing Combinatory Terms of a Given Type

Tags: logic, proof-theory, constructive-mathematics, lambda-calculus, type-theory

I have the following problem as an assignment: to construct a combinatory term of type $$(p \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r))$$ using the polymorphic $\mathbb{K}, \mathbb{S}$ combinators. I know the relevant definitions, but am not sure how to start tackling the problem.

Could someone please post a combinatory term for a simpler type, for example $$(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$$ or even $$((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r)$$ if the former is too similar to the actual problem (I don't know how much of a blowup in size there is from type to combinators) and explain how to derive it? I'd like to complete my actual assignment problem on my own, so a worked example for something similar and simpler would set me on the right path to do that, I think. Alternatively, any recommendations for relevant resources already available online would also be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: as originally posted, the type of the first term was incorrect (there was a $q$ in place of the first $r$). As it was, the question would've been impossible - since of course $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r))$ (which was the original, typoed version) is not a theorem of any reasonable logic.

Comment: Do you have something else appart from K, S? I don't see the way to get something of type `r` out of nowhere. (If you know something about logic, this is equivalent to trying to prove the implication `(p→q)→(p→(q→r))`)

Comment: Nope, only the K,S combinators. I can of course apply those combinators to elements of type in {p, q, r}, though. The idea is that the S,K combinators encode the implicational fragment of intuitionistic logic, and of course I can prove $(p \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r))$ by natural deduction in that system. My issue is that I'm having trouble understanding how to express that proof exclusively with combinators.

Comment: How do you prove $(p→r)→(p→(q→r))$ by natural deduction? I mean, I strongly suspect it's not possible. Oh! Maybe that's the sole purpose of the exercise..

Comment: While perhaps overkill for this example, the easiest thing to do would to write the corresponding lambda term and then use [bracket abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis) to produce the SK combinators (and then attempt to assign types or show that bracket abstraction preserves typability). Finding the lambda term is a fairly mechanical process and is indeed mechanized in e.g. the [Djinn utility](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinnhttps://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn).